# Android Sqlite Database Connection

Tags: android, sqlite

When connecting to the Sqlite database it will show some error.. And also it need to be create seperate Sqlite database in each device.. How to create that one automatically,?

Comment: Could you add the stacktrace and be more specific about you error?

Comment: missing a space on your `CREATE TABLE` string. Should be `KEY_RANK + " TEXT NOT NULL"` instead of `KEY_RANK + "TEXT NOT NULL"`.

Comment: sorry for the incomplete post viewers.. I rectify that problem very easy manner

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 public Data getdata(int id) {
  Cursor cursor = db.query(DATABASE_TABLE, new String[] {KEY_ROWID,
                   KEY_NAME, KEY_RANK }, KEY_ID + "=?",
                    new String[] { String.valueOf(id) }, null, null, null, null);
            if (cursor != null)
                cursor.moveToFirst();

            Data data = new Data(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)),
                    cursor.getString(1), cursor.getString(2));
            // return name
            return data;
}
```

Create an Activity Class and call the read data parameters using ur Model class

```
 txt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView4);
            txt1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView5);
            txt2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView6);

            bt.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {



                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    viewData();
                }

                private void viewData() {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    try {
                        // ask the database manager for data
                        name = db.getdata(id);
                        txt.setText(name._name);
                        txt1.setText(name._rank);
    }
}
```

In ur **onCreate(SQLitedatabase db)**

```
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + DATABASE_TABLE + " (" +
                        KEY_ROWID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
                        KEY_NAME + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
                        KEY_RANK + " TEXT NOT NULL "+ ")");
```

}

Comment: please tell me whats wrong with the code??

Comment: what is `Name`? Shouldn't `getdata()` return a `String` instead of `Name`? and your execSQL statement, I don't see why you need to split the `TEXT NOT NULL` and `)`. So the downvote.

Comment: Name was the from my code from where i copied it .. i forgot to rectify it... My Bad :(

Comment: i had used a model class to set & get

Comment: @Aprian : & the Text not null was written incorrectly. Just check

Comment: Yes I know you are using POJO, you may need to change the return type of getdata to `Name` instead of `String`. And I think the problem on the statement is the space between `KEY_RANK` and `TEXT NOT NULL`. Not the `")"`

Comment: Eh, I meant, should be `public Data getdata(int id)` instead of `public String getdata(int id)` since you create a new Object named `Data` and you are returning it to the method.